# Decoding bytes and SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have read previous questions on the subject but none mentioned bytes. I have bytestrings (?) like the following in a pandas dataframe: `\u0393\u03b9\u03ce\u03c1\u03b3\u03bf\u03c2 
 u039d\u03c4\u03b1\u03bb\u03ac\u03c1\u03b1\u03c2` and I've tried to convert them to human readable output. The language of the text is Greek, the data was read from a JSON file (json.load / loads didn't help much, and neither did pd.read_json).

When I am trying to print such an object, it prints the bytes.

Example code with prints:

```
lst = ['\\u0393\\u03b9\\u03ce\\u03c1\\u03b3\\u03bf\\u03c2 \\u039d\\u03c4\\u03b1\\u03bb\\u03ac\\u03c1\\u03b1\\u03c2',
     '\\u0393\\u03b9\\u03ce\\u03c1\\u03b3\\u03bf\\u03c2 \\u039d\\u03c4\\u03b1\\u03bb\\u03ac\\u03c1\\u03b1\\u03c2',
     '\\u0393\\u03b9\\u03ce\\u03c1\\u03b3\\u03bf\\u03c2 \\u039d\\u03c4\\u03b1\\u03bb\\u03ac\\u03c1\\u03b1\\u03c2']

df= pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=["some_bytestrings"])

print(df["some_bytestrings"]) 
# prints: \u0393\u03b9\u03ce\u03c1\u03b3\u03bf\u03c2 \u0...

print(df['some_bytestrings'].values[0]) 
# prints: \u0393\u03b9\u03ce\u03c1\u03b3\u03bf\u03c2 \u039d\u03c4\u03b1\u03bb\u03ac\u03c1\u03b1\u03c2

# eval seems to work for some previous data, don't know why
print(eval(dfsmall['some_bytestrings'].values[0])) 
# ERROR ARISES HERE

print('\\u0393\\u03b9\\u03ce\\u03c1\\u03b3\\u03bf\\u03c2 \\u039d\\u03c4\\u03b1\\u03bb\\u03ac\\u03c1\\u03b1\\u03c2')
# prints \u0393\u03b9\u03ce\u03c1\u03b3\u03bf\u03c2 \u039d\u03c4\u03b1\u03bb\u03ac\u03c1\u03b1\u03c2

print(print(dfsmall['some_bytestrings'].values[0].encode().decode()))
# decoding encoding doesn't work, it prints: \u0393\u03b9\u03ce\u03c1\u03b3\u03bf\u03c2 \u039d\u03c4\u03b1\u03bb\u03ac\u03c1\u03b1\u03c2
```

Note that if I take the printed output and print again, it turns out fine:

```
print("\u0393\u03b9\u03ce\u03c1\u03b3\u03bf\u03c2 \u039d\u03c4\u03b1\u03bb\u03ac\u03c1\u03b1\u03c2")
# prints: 'Γιώργος Νταλάρας'
```

As it seems to me it has to do with how Python handles the double slashes (`\\`), but I cannot seem to work around a solution to this, since methods like `string.replace("\\\\", "\\")` don't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've labeled then "byte_strings" (`bytes` type) but from your outputs they are actually text strings (`str` type) that contain escape sequences.

Fortunately, python includes a codec for decoding the string escapes called `unicode_escape`.

You can decode these strings using the `codecs` module -- for example:

```
>>> codecs.decode('\\u0393\\u03b9\\u03ce\\u03c1\\u03b3\\u03bf\\u03c2 \\u039d\\u03c4\\u03b1\\u03bb\\u03ac\\u03c1\\u03b1\\u03c2', 'unicode_escape')
'Γιώργος Νταλάρας'
```